# I am having error when ever i am trying to call _id parameter in my angular front-end

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb

EmployeeComponent.html: 11 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined
    This is the error I am having when ever I try to call the id in my angular front-end

I have tried using ngIf but it still gives me error

Here I am having error

```
<div class="col s5" >
    <form   #employeeForm='ngForm'(ngSubmit)="onSubmit(employeeForm)">
        <input type="hidden" name="_id" #_id="ngModel"[(ngModel)]="employeeService.selectedEmployee._id" class="col s5">                           
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="input-field col s12">
                                    <input type="text" name='name' #name='ngModel'[(ngModel)]="employeeService.selectedEmployee.name" placeholder="Enter Full name" class="input-field col s12" required>
                                    <label >Name :
                                        <label class="red-text">*</label>
                                    </label>
                                </div>                               
                            </div>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please share your code and what you have tried so far. so others can help you.

Answer (score 0):

According to your code of just Angular, their can be many possibilities. One would be that your backend would not have sent you _id to you in frontend. first just verify that you are getting the proper data

Comment: thnks everyone for your kind response i am able to solve my problem